# Does such Holomorphic function exist on open unit disc?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be a holomorphic function on unit disc in $\bf C$.

$1.$ $f( 1- \frac{1}{n})= {(1-\frac {1}{n}})^2$ for $n \in \bf N$.Does this implies that $f(z)=z^2$ ?

$2$ $f(\frac {1}{n})=\frac {1}{n^2}$ for $ n\in \bf N$.Does this implies that  $f(z)=z^2$. ?

Clearly By Identity theorem $2$ holds.But I'm not sure about $1$ since  $1- \frac{1}{n}$ $\to$ $1$ as $n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Use $\displaystyle g(z)=\sin(\frac{\pi}{1-z})$

Comment: +1,Thank you! How did you find this example?

Comment: As you have remarked, $z_n=1-\frac{1}{n}\to 1$. So computing $1-z_n$ and remembering that $\sin(n\pi )=0$, was natural.

Comment: Ahh,I see.Thank you again.Regards,

Answer (score 1):

It's interesting to note that the answer to $1$ is true if we assume $f\in H^1(\mathbb D)$. Suppose $g(z)$ is a function satisfying the given condition and consider $h(z)=g(z)-z^2$. By [Szego's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blaschke_product), $h(z)$ is identically zero, so $g\equiv z^2$.

Comment: By $H^1$ you mean holomorphic function?

Comment: @Dontknowanything See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy_space#Hardy_spaces_for_the_unit_disk